# Bootstrap in communities

Tags: community, css, bootstrap

In communities, is  there  a way of uploading bootstrap.css file onto site.com. I  tried to upload a document and convert it to css but it comes up with a message saying that I can't upload it due to too many errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better off just using your Force.com domain and doing it through there: You have to Enable Community and then create it. Following that it will appear under

```
`Setup > Develop > Sites
```

Inside of there you will have all your pages. Put a css file inside of

```
Setup > Develop > Static Resources
```

and then you can connect it through one of your pages in such a way :

```
 <!-- Style -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'css/bootstrap.css')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'css/style.css')}"/>
        <!-- Responsive -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'css/responsive.css')}"/>
        <!-- Choose Layout -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'css/layout-semiboxed.css')}"/>
        <!-- Choose Skin -->
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'css/skin-HAL.min.css')}"/>
        <!-- Favicon -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{!URLFOR($Resource.Calypso_resources, 'img/favicon.ico')}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
        <!-- IE -->
        <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
```